# How to sort table tbodies in html with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I'm encountered this problem from my workplace and i kinda feel this table isn't common table for me. I want to sort this table like when i click one of the header, it got sorted from that header category. In example i have this html code:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="AirflightDetail">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-lg-2 text-center">Airline</th>
                <th class="col-lg-2 text-center">Depart</th>
                <th class="col-lg-2 text-center">Arrival</th>
                <th class="col-lg-2 text-center">Duration</th>
                <th class="col-lg-2 text-center">Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="table-result-list">
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="87px">
                    <span>Airline X</span>
                    <br>
                    <p>AX-006</p>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="100px">
                        <strong>13:10</strong>
                        <br>
                        <span>Singapore</span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="100px">
                        <strong>14:25</strong>
                        <br>
                        <span>Bangkok</span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="65px">
                        <strong>1hour 15m</strong>
                        <br>
                        <span>Direct</span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right amount" min-width="77px">
                        <strong>$327</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tbody class="table-result-list">
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="87px">
                    <span>Airline H</span>
                    <br>
                    <p>AH-999</p>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="100px">
                        <strong>18:30</strong>
                        <br>
                        <span>Singapore</span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="100px">
                        <strong>19:45</strong>
                        <br>
                        <span>Bangkok</span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="65px">
                        <strong>1hour 15m</strong>
                        <br>
                        <span>Direct </span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right amount" min-width="77px">
                        <strong>$273</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tbody class="table-result-list">
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="87px">
                    <span>Airline K</span>
                    <br>
                    <p>AK-100</p>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="100px">
                        <strong>12:05</strong>
                        <br>
                        <span>Singapore</span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="100px">
                        <strong>14:20</strong>
                        <br>
                        <span>Bangkok</span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="65px">
                        <strong>2hour</strong>
                        <br>
                        <span>Direct </span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right amount" min-width="77px">
                        <strong>$273</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

When i click the header title in example Airline, the table got sorted from the airline like:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="AirflightDetail">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-lg-2 text-center">Airline</th>
                <th class="col-lg-2 text-center">Depart</th>
                <th class="col-lg-2 text-center">Arrival</th>
                <th class="col-lg-2 text-center">Duration</th>
                <th class="col-lg-2 text-center">Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="table-result-list">
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="87px">
                    <span>Airline H</span>
                    <br>
                    <p>AH-999</p>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="100px">
                        <strong>18:30</strong>
                        <br>
                        <span>Singapore</span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="100px">
                        <strong>19:45</strong>
                        <br>
                        <span>Bangkok</span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="65px">
                        <strong>1hour 15m</strong>
                        <br>
                        <span>Direct </span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right amount" min-width="77px">
                        <strong>$273</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tbody class="table-result-list">
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="87px">
                    <span>Airline K</span>
                    <br>
                    <p>AK-100</p>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="100px">
                        <strong>12:05</strong>
                        <br>
                        <span>Singapore</span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="100px">
                        <strong>14:20</strong>
                        <br>
                        <span>Bangkok</span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="65px">
                        <strong>2hour</strong>
                        <br>
                        <span>Direct </span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right amount" min-width="77px">
                        <strong>$273</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

         <tbody class="table-result-list">
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="87px">
                    <span>Airline X</span>
                    <br>
                    <p>AX-006</p>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="100px">
                        <strong>13:10</strong>
                        <br>
                        <span>Singapore</span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="100px">
                        <strong>14:25</strong>
                        <br>
                        <span>Bangkok</span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" min-width="65px">
                        <strong>1hour 15m</strong>
                        <br>
                        <span>Direct</span>
                </td>
                <td class="text-right amount" min-width="77px">
                        <strong>$327</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I've already seen many javascript sort the table but it only sort the element of tbody  or  but i never seen any javascript that can sorting the tbody. How can i do that with javascript and without jquery

Comment: You can use a plugin such as [datatable](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: Can you explain the sort logic ?

Comment: @Burimi Its like when i click the one of the thead th, the table got sorted from that th, in example when i click airlines, the table got sorted ascending from the airlines. The table was composed with multiple tbodies and the values was in there. Its like sorting the value from different tbodies and recreate the table with sorted tbodies.

Comment: @MaximalSnowman So you want to sort a single tbody based on what user clicks ? And if that is the case, what values are taken into account for sorting ? By their dates, city ?

Comment: @Burimi Hmmm its more like sorting the tbodies from what those tbodies got. Its depends from what user clicks, If the user click on the "Depart", the table got sorted from the earliest flight time. If the users click on the "Price", the table got sorted from the cheapest price.

Comment: jquery datatable is best for this purpose

Comment: @MaximalSnowman I was facing the same issue and I shared the solution   here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635421/create-a-generic-sortabletable-object-to-be-used-to-alphabetically-sort-a-table Does it help you?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bunch of stuff involved on this one.

First of all you have to attach event listeners to all your thead th items so when they are clicked they'll perform the sort action.

```
var airFlightTable = document.querySelector("#AirflightDetail");

var tableHeaders = airFlightTable.querySelectorAll("thead tr th");

tableHeaders.forEach(function(tableHeader){

  tableHeader.addEventListener("click", onTableHeaderClick);
});
```

When click happens you start the sort process by gathering all `tbody` tags and manipulate their DOM.

```
function onTableHeaderClick(event){

  var sortBy = event.currentTarget.innerHTML;

  if(sortBy === 'Airline'){

    airFlightTable.querySelectorAll(".table-result-list").forEach(function(tableResultsLIst){

      var items = [].slice.call(tableResultsLIst.querySelectorAll("td"));

      var sortedItems = items.sort(); //you can place your sort logic here and after you're done you have to replace items of current tbody with sorted ones
    });
  }
}
```

There is some work left for you, but you should be fine from this point. Here is a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/difuloy/edit?html,js) with this implementation

Comment: it would be easier `var th=document.getElementById('AirflightDetail').getElementsByTagName('th');` rather then `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` ... ? in the adding event listeners part

Comment: thanks for your help @Burimi, im still trying to figuring out how to use this. Seems like there will be a lot things that i need to do.