# Create a generic sortableTable object to be used to alphabetically sort a table elements each time a column is clicked using only JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting, columnsorting

I'm working on project which don't use jQuery but only JavaScript and we have a need to sort alphabetically ascending a table values (without any external library).

The objective is to sort rows elements each time a column (*th* element) is clicked.

**Example**

If I have this table

[image]

When I click on "Names", the table should be refreshed like that:

[image]

When I click on "Tel", the table should be refreshed like that:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sharing my own solution here. If you have any remark or suggestions, please share.

**I'm updating my solution by adding an inverse order feature**:

- When you first click on *Names* for example, the table will be refreshed with an **ascending order** of names.
- When you click a 2nd time on *Names*, the table will be refreshed with a **descending order** of names.
- When you click a 3rd time on *Names*, the table will be refreshed with an **ascending order** of names.
- etc...

```js
var sortableTable = {
 /**
 * The table to sort
 */
 table: null,
 getTable: function(){
  return this.table;
 },
 setTable: function(table){
  this.table = table;
 },
 /**
 * The column used for sorting
 */ 
 element: null,
 getElement: function(){
  return this.element;
 },
 setElement: function(element){
  this.element = element;
 },
    /**
    * When ooderDirection is 1 => Ascending order 
    * When ooderDirection is -1 => Descending order 
    */
 orderDirection: 1,
 getOrderDirection: function(){
  return this.orderDirection;
 },
 setOrderDirection: function(orderDirection){
  this.orderDirection = orderDirection;
 },
 /**
 * Get table rows elements
 */  
 getRows: function(){
  var rows = [];
  if(null !== this.getTable()){
   var allRows = this.getTable().rows;
   /*
    When I returned allRows directly, 
    in the sort function when I do: rows.sort();
    it display an error: Uncaught TypeError: rows.sort is not a function
    So I'm converting this object to an array
   */
   var arrayRows = [];
   //allRows contains all rows with <th> elements, 
   //so I'm removing th elements (index 0)
   for(let i=1 ; i<allRows.length ; i++){
    arrayRows.push(allRows[i]);
   }
   return (arrayRows);
  }
  return null;
 },
 /**
 * Display rows using the sort result
 */  
 refresh: function(rows){
  for(let i=0 ; i<rows.length ; i++){
   this.getTable().appendChild(rows[i]);
  }
 },
 /**
 * Sort alphabetically (ASC)
 */  
 sort: function(indexOfClickedTh){
  var rows = this.getRows();
        var that = this;
  rows.sort(function(item1, item2){
   var contentItem1 = item1.getElementsByTagName('td')[indexOfClickedTh].innerText;
   var contentItem2 = item2.getElementsByTagName('td')[indexOfClickedTh].innerText;
   let resultCompare = contentItem1.localeCompare(contentItem2);
            resultCompare = resultCompare * that.getOrderDirection();
   //console.info('comparing(' + contentItem1 + ', ' + contentItem2 + ')=' + resultCompare); 
   return resultCompare;
  });
  this.refresh(rows);
 }
}


//The first click will generate an ascending sort
var initialOderDirection = -1;

var myTableToSort = document.getElementById('users');
sortableTable.setTable(myTableToSort);
sortableTable.setOrderDirection(initialOderDirection);
var ListOfTh = document.getElementById('users').getElementsByTagName('th');
for(var i=0 ; i<ListOfTh.length ; i++){
 var oneTh = ListOfTh[i];
 oneTh.addEventListener("click", function(){
        //console.info("------> New sort based on '" + this.innerText + "' <------");
      
        // Set the current clicked <th> element
  sortableTable.setElement(this);
      
        //Inverse the order
        sortableTable.setOrderDirection( sortableTable.getOrderDirection() * -1 );
        
        //Do the sort and refresh table result
  sortableTable.sort(this.cellIndex); 
 });
};
```

```css
table{
    font-size: 16px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
table th{
    padding-top: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    background-color: #6295a5;
    color: white;
}
table td{
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
table th{
 cursor: pointer;
}
table th:hover{
 color: #dea82e;
 background-color: #37545d;
}
```

```html
<table id="users">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Names</th>
   <th>Functions</th>
   <th>Emails</th>
   <th>Tel</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>xMxxx</td>
   <td>Physicists</td>
   <td>xmxxx@domain.com</td>
   <td>00 55 99 99 99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>xJxxx</td>
   <td>Air Traffic Controllers</td>
   <td>xjxxx@domain.com</td>
   <td>00 22 99 99 99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>xExxx</td>
   <td>Engineer</td>
   <td>xexxx@domain.com</td>
   <td>00 33 99 99 99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>xAxxx</td>
   <td>Mechanical engineer</td>
   <td>xaxxx@domain.com</td>
   <td>00 11 99 99 99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>xZxxx</td>
   <td>Doctor</td>
   <td>xzxxx@domain.com</td>
   <td>00 44 99 99 99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>xPxxx</td>
   <td>Professor</td>
   <td>xpxxx@domain.com</td>
   <td>00 66 99 99 99</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i get an error: `Object doesn't support property or method 'append'`

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm testing on Chrome 54 and I don't see the error, Which browser are you using so I can fix?

Comment: @NinaScholz The same error I'm seeing in my Edge too. I need to fix that

Comment: you could change `this.getTable().append(rows[i]);` to `this.getTable().appendChild(rows[i]);`

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks it's solving the issue on Edge... I updated the solution so others can use it.

Comment: I'm adding a `sortableTable.orderDirection` to inverse order each time a header `<th>` element is clicked.

Comment: now you need an order indicator for the column, too.