# JQuery table sorter wrong parser matches

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, tablesorter

I use JQuery table sorter for sorting columns in table. I faced problem. I have similar values in my column: 1-21-909 - SOME TEXT. This format of cell matches shortDate regular expression in jquery.tablesorter.js. And as the result, it sorts them in wrong way. Guys, please, is anybody knows, how to specify , that this is text format of the value?

Thank you

Comment: Does my question here helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635421/create-a-generic-sortabletable-object-to-be-used-to-alphabetically-sort-a-table   ?

Answer (score 0):

if someone will force such issue. The solution is simple: just add sorter: 'text' (or some other type) to  tag.